# Delphi Keeps going to last ListBox item with threading

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am trying to make this program using multi thread with delphi it doesn't seem to be going through multiple items just goes through the last one every time instead of selecting multiple

You can see the pic it will explain that it only goes to the last and not the rest of the items

Any Help is great thanks!

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Index2: Integer;
begin
 for Index2 := 0 to ListBox2.Items.Count - 1 do
 begin
   ListBox2.ItemIndex := Index2;
   LastName := ListBox2.Items.Strings[Index2];
   with T1.Create do
     FreeOnTerminate := True;
  end;
end;
```

[image: PIC OF THE ERROR]

Comment: What is the question? Can you give a complete program that demonstrates the behaviour you are referring to.

Comment: Added a pic i hope you understand it i want it to select multiple items using threads

Comment: Your code shows no attempt to select anything. So, I guess that's the problem. All you do is fire off a thread. What that thread does, only you know.

Comment: It does have the for listbox2 items statement

Comment: If am doing it wrong mind giving me an example with multi select items?

Comment: You are not attempting to select anything. Use `ListBox.Selected[index] := True` to select an item. You must execute that code in the main thread. Please step back and read your question from our perspective. Imagine you are us. How can we possibly understand what you are trying to achieve. Spending a bit more time clarifying your thoughts before asking questions would help you to ask better questions and get better responses.

Comment: Well what am trying to make is a FTP connection to recover lost passwords it really slow with making it get through an password 1 by one i need it to select multiple and connect to them using those passwords i already got the username selection working all i need it to do is select Multiple passwords and try to connect with it.

Comment: I think I've said enough here. You need to fix the question. Adding bits and pieces in comments won't get it done. Please take the time to improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program runs through the 4 items in your listbox, and for each item it starts a thread (that runs in the background) and then continues with the next item in the listbox - even though the thread hasn't finished processing.

If you in your T1 thread reads the ListBox2.SelectedIndex, then it will most likely read the last item, as your thread will most likely only reach the reading of the SelectedIndex after the FOR loop has finished. Remember that the thread you are starting is running simultaneously as your main thread, ie. your main thread doesn't suddently stop running just because you start a new thread (that's the whole point of multi-threading).

Instead, you should pass the index for the thread to process into the thread as you are creating it, by re-making the Create CONSTRUCTOR to accept a listbox and/or the item to process, or - even better - do the readout of the data you need from the ListBox2 and pass that onto the Create CONSTRUCTOR of the thread. You should not access VCL components from threads - especially not if those same components are updated in the main thread at the same time (which is what is the problem here).